# How to get elements from the end with PHPQuery?

Tags: php, parsing, phpquery

How can I get element by order from the end?

For example, I need to get second item from the end.

```
<?php
  $html = <<<EOD
<div style="text-align: center;" class="navigation">
        <span class="pagination">
          <span>« novější</span> | 
          <span>1</span> | 
          <a href="?listType=&amp;sort=&amp;page=1">2</a> | 
          <a href="?listType=&amp;sort=&amp;page=2">3</a> | 
          <a href="?listType=&amp;sort=&amp;page=3">4</a> | 
          <a href="?listType=&amp;sort=&amp;page=1">starší »</a>
        </span>
      </div>
EOD;

  $dom = PHPQuery::newDocument($html);
  var_dump($dom->find('.navigation > .pagination > *')->eq(-2)->text());
  var_dump($dom->find('.navigation > .pagination > *:last-child(2)')->text());
```

But instead of 4 this code returns:

```
string(0) ""
string(11) "starší »"
```

Comment: Do you want this `starší` as output?

Comment: Why not: $dom->find('.navigation > .pagination > *:eq(-2)')->text() ? Does last-child(2) take arguments in PHPQuery, because in jQuery it does not and returns just the last child which is "starší »" in your case.

Answer (score 0):

Hope this will help you out. Here we are using `DOMDocument` and `DOMXPath` to get the desired output.

```
<?php
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
$html = <<<EOD
<div style="text-align: center;" class="navigation">
        <span class="pagination">
          <span>« novější</span> | 
          <span>1</span> | 
          <a href="?listType=&amp;sort=&amp;page=1">2</a> | 
          <a href="?listType=&amp;sort=&amp;page=2">3</a> | 
          <a href="?listType=&amp;sort=&amp;page=3">4</a> | 
          <a href="?listType=&amp;sort=&amp;page=1">starší »</a>
        </span>
      </div>
EOD;
$domObject= new DOMDocument();
$domObject->loadHTML($html);

$domQuery= new DOMXPath($domObject);
$results=$domQuery->query('//span[@class="pagination"]/a');
$contents=array();
foreach ($results as $result)
{
    $contents[]=$result->textContent;
}
print_r(array_reverse($contents));
```

**Output:**

```
Array
(
    [0] => starší »
    [1] => 4
    [2] => 3
    [3] => 2
)
```